# How to create a NSToolbarItem with a custom view

Tags: appkit, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

How can you create a custom NSToolbarItem that appears like say the Safari address bar?

[image]

More specifically, one that has the background color, shadow and rounded corners.
Additionally, it responds to the inactive stage of the window

[image]

as well as supporting Dark Mode in macOS Mojave.

[image]

Is it done via the use of an NSBox? Is it using a custom NSButton?
Just to clarify. I am familiar with the intricacies of Dark Mode, how to make rounded corners, create a NSToolbarItem with a custom view etc.

I am looking for a canonical answer as to how to create a custom NSToolbarItem that adheres to the principles of the ones provided by AppKit.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom NSButton to achieve almost the same [thing](https://ds9soft.com/2018/10/03/progress-update-3/). I didn’t try to use an NSSearchField, but with an NSTextField the progress bar didn’t blend well in Mojave, so I switched to an NSButton. The caveat is making it an editable text field, something I haven’t done yet. You will also need to implement your own custom cell to draw text and icons.